# Youtube iframe video in featherlight lightbox continues to play after lightbox closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am building one of my first webpages and am very novice when it comes to any custom html, js, css, etc. I'm building the site in Squarespace on the Alex template. My goal is to have a lightbox that opens from a text link and plays a youtbe video. Currently, I am able to get the text link to open a lightbox (featherlight) and play a youtube video (iframe embed), but then I run into 2 problems.
1. The audio for the video plays twice
2. when I close the light box, one set of the audio keeps playing.

I am totally lost here and have scoured trying to find a solution. Here's what I have:

```html
<a id='open_lightbox' data-featherlight='.lightbox_content' href='#'>open lightbox</a>
<div style="display:none;">
<div class='lightbox_content'id=ytplayer>
    <iframe id="video1" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g7fbe-oV-X0?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>
 $("#open_lightbox").click(function(){
  $("#video1")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
  ev.preventDefault();
 });
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

A lot of this is taken from different posts, but I haven't found anything that works. This is the last bit I had worked out that gets the video to play, but I don't know how to stop it, or why there are two audio instances running. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.#open_lightbox').on('click', function(ev) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#video1")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
        },150);

    //ev.preventDefault();
});
```

The way you do it used to work - I just had to use the trick again and faced the same problems. Adding a small delay and remove the preventDefault() worked for me.

You might need to put a more specific jQuery selector for the "#video1" so it isn't auto-playing two videos.